# Como alterar valor inserido pelo usuário em formulário do CreateView (Django) antes de salvar no banco de dados

Tags: python, django, forms

Estou criando um sistema simples (apenas para aprendizado) para controle de compras, consumo, estoque, etc.

No formulário, o usuário irá informar: DATA,  TIPO DE TRANSAÇÃO (compra ou venda), o PRODUTO, QUANTIDADE.

A ideia seria um controle  mais ou menos assim:

| 01/08/2022 | compra  | produto A | 2 |

| 01/08/2022 | compra  | produto B | 3 |

| 03/08/2022 | consumo | produto B | 1 |

| 05/08/2022 | compra  | produto A | 1 |

Eu gostaria que sempre que fosse marcada a opção consumo, automaticamente o valor da quantidade já seria inserido no banco de dados com valor negativo.

EM MODELS...

```
tiposdescricao_choices = (
        ('CP', 'Compra'),
        ('CS', 'Consumo'),
        ('IV', 'inventário'),
    )
    
    class Historico(models.Model):
        data = models.DateField()
        descricao = models.CharField(choices= tiposdescricao_choices, max_length=2)
        produto = models.ForeignKey(Produtos, on_delete = models.CASCADE)
        quantidade = models.FloatField()
    
        def __str__(self):
            return self.descricao
```

EM VIEWS

```
from django.urls import reverse_lazy
class HistoricoCreate(CreateView):
    model = Historico
    fields =  '__all__'
```

Answer (score 0):

Você pode fazer isso de duas formas:

Você pode sobrescrever o método "save" dentro do model, seria mais ou menos assim:

```
def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
    # este if serve para que a condição só seja executada em create
    if not self.pk:
        if self.descricao == 'CS':
            self.valor_negativo = 12345
    super().save(*args, **kwargs)
```

Nesta abordagem, você precisará criar o atributo valor_negativo do tipo decimal para registrar esses valores. Basta que você atribua a self.valor_negativo o resultado do calculo negativo que você deseja fazer com base na quantidade.

A segunda abordagem é na Createview, customizando o método form_valid, esta é a abordagem que prefiro utilizar, particularmente não gosto de mexer tanto na model, gosto de deixar o mais enxuto possível.

```
class HistoricoCreate(CreateView):
    model = Historico
    fields =  '__all__'

    def form_valid(self, form):
        if form.instance.descricao == 'CS':
            form.instance.valor_negativo = 12345
        return super().form_valid(form)
```

Isso deve atender a tua necessidade.